# Wordpress nginx preview post is 404 not found, but old posts are working

Tags: wordpress, nginx, varnish, permalinks

I recently moved my wordpress site from one host to another. Previously i used **Apache** to run wordpress, but later on configured with **nginx** by following this tutorial [**How to Install Wordpress with nginx on Ubuntu 12.04**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Everything works fine, but when i try to preview a new post from the admin panel it is showing not found error. But all already published posts are working fine.

When i click on preview post it is showing me url like 
http://mydomain.com/?p=2671&preview=true but the page is 404.

The page title has **Nothing found for ?p=2671&preview=true**

My nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen    127.0.0.1:8080;
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/mysite/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mydomain.com;   

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }       

    location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;

    }   
}
```

I also have installed **All In One SEO Pack** plugin and from my admin i enabled permalinks to this format **/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/**

I searched lot of forums but still couldn't find the exact solution. Kindly help me on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. It is the **problem with Varnish configuration**, it is not allowing to create a cookie.

Open the varnish configuration. In my case the file is at `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` and add the following line

```
# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
sub vcl_recv {
        # Allow posts preview 
        if (req.url ~ "preview=true") { 
                return(pass); 
        }
        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }
}
```

and restart the nginx and varnish

```
sudo service nginx restart

sudo service varnish restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your issue on Ubuntu 12.04+nginx+php-fpm but without effect. It means that previewing works as expected. The only difference is I've uncommented line fast_cgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 and commented out the other one. As I see you've put 'varnish' in tags, so maybe it's problem with varnish as suggested here -> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nginx-cant-preview-posts-404-error

Answer (score 0):

All i needed in my wordpress server is only 2 blocks

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
}
location ~ \.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # replaced this with ur sock location
}
```

I don't know about the SEO plugin, i use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```